# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe4' at position

Tags: python-2.7, unicode, character-encoding

I know that this question has previous answers. But my problem here is little different. My problem is that I need to remove this bug and I do not know the actual string. My job is to find out code that is causing this bug. I only know traceback from log file and it told me that error is in this line of code:

```
return unicode(",",join(str(blocker.reason) for blocker in story.blocked_instances.all()))
```

I think that cause of error is unicode function as when it is trying to encode a string containing unicode character u'\xe4', the error is raised. Am I correct in thinking so? If not, then please tell me how should I prceed to debug this error?

Comment: The problem is as you say, one or more of the joined strings is in fact some binary encoding and the `unicode` encoding fails. You could add `encoding=???` to the call, but how can you know what the encoding is? Maybe its utf-8, maybe its some code page. The fix is deeper down at the edge where something is reading in encoded binary but treating it as a string. Python 3 enforces disciple at the edges which is one reason why its unicode support is so much better.

Comment: @tdelaney thanks for your help. I found the problem. Database is storing data in unicode format and str is using ascii format for encoding. Hence, when a character with integer value greater than is encountered, it is raising error. I have removed str and unicode function. Now, it should work fine.